# Most efficient way to insert table content to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I have two tables with different schema. The tables are in two separate databases on two servers.

How can I copy the content from one table to the other? I have several million rows to move.

Does this query work for tables in different servers?

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column_name(s))
   SELECT column_name(s)
   FROM table1;
```

Thanks

UPDATE:

I realized I'm inserting data to a non-sql database.

Here's the scenario:
I have a table in SQL Server Database and I want to move the data to an IBM Database.

There are several millions rows in my SQL table.

I need to unload the data and store as flat file. The format can be .csv or txt.

The "Task->Export" function does not work.
Millions of records being transferred across the network will ultimately timeout due to latency and maximum connection time established.

So is there any other ways to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46289/which-one-is-more-efficient-select-from-linked-server-or-insert-into-linked-ser  If you choose Linked Servers, take note the one article linked in the accepted answer which suggests running the query on the receiving server.  Pushing through a linked server appears to run row-by-row.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, performing this in a query would be the most efficient way of doing this...

You just have to qualify the name:

```
myDatabase.dbo.myTable
```

(assuming dbo is the right schema)

Or do you mean cross server/instance transactions? Then you need to set up a [Linked Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx) and again, fully qualify the name:

```
 myLinkedServer.myDatabase.dbo.myTable
```

Comment: I've eddited your answer to include the relevant links to msdn. Also, I would recomend disabeling indexes, triggers, and perhaps constraints as well on the recieving table.